# Pivot and transform df in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

my input:

```
df<-data.frame("frame"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
               "label_x"=c("AO","Other","AO","GS","GS","RF","RF","TI",NA,"Other"),
               "label_y"=c("AO","RF","RF", "GS","GS","Other","Other","TI","AO","RF"),
               "cross"=c("Matched","Mismatched", "Mismatched","Matcehed","Matched"
                         ,"Mismatched", "Mismatched","Mismatched","Mismatched","Mismatched")  )
```

I want to count all "Matches/Mismatches" from column `cross` per label, for column `label_x` and `label_y` (both). So I tried this code for each column `label_`:

```
 df %>%  filter(!is.na(label_y )) %>%  group_by(label_y) %>% count(cross)
```

but it doesn't answer my question, after that I need to sum the counts for each column .
So I expect something like this...:

```
label  Mismatching Matching Total
AO       5           7         13
RF       3           4          7
```

Comment: There is a typo - "Matcehed", is it on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to do it:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(label_x ,label_y), values_to = "label") %>% 
   group_by(label) %>% count(cross) %>%   
   pivot_wider(values_from = n, names_from = cross, values_fill = 0) %>% 
   mutate(total = Matched + Mismatched)
```

Result tibble:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   label [6]
  label Matched Mismatched total
  <chr>   <int>      <int> <int>
1 AO          2          2     4
2 GS          4          0     4
3 Other       0          4     4
4 RF          0          5     5
5 TI          0          2     2
6 NA          0          1     1
```

However, keep in mind that the matched number is overestimated because both label_x and label_y have been used. Could you show a result table with the real labels and number you expect ?

Comment: That the problem, I don't know really number. I think overestimated is ok for me, because for example AO was used in label_x and in label_y, so it was "used" twice. The original df come as you see after join two tables by frame and checking if label_x equally to label_y. Or you think its wrong calculation?

Comment: I'm not able to answer your question without a bit more information about the context. What do these data represent, what are you aiming with those matches etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using *table*:

```
table(data.frame(label = unlist(df[, c("label_x", "label_y")]), 
                 cross = df$cross))
#       cross
#label   Matcehed Matched Mismatched
#  AO           0       2          2
#  GS           2       2          0
#  Other        0       0          4
#  RF           0       0          5
#  TI           0       0          2
```